# PHP - selected HTML form value based on PDO value

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I have an HTML form and I have a select menu. I would like that according to the value chosen by the user this would be the same value that is selected on HTML form. For example if the user chooses HIDE - the value in the select will be HIDE, if the user chooses SHOW - the value would be SHOW.

I have managed to change the value in the SQL table using PDO but I haven't managed to display the selected option based on the SQL table. Regardless of what is being saved in the table - the value being displayed in the HTML form is always show.

```
<select id="address_privacy" name="address_privacy" tabindex="auto">
<option "<?php if($result['address_privacy'] == 'SHOW') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?>" value="SHOW">Show Physical Location</option>
<option "<?php if($result['address_privacy'] == 'HIDE') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>" value="HIDE">Hide Physical Location</option>

</select>
```

The above is waht I tried till now.

Comment: You are passing the new value with `=`, comparing is `==`.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: + the <option> will end up with "selected="selected""
You can remove the " before the <?php and the one after ?>

Comment: Also the `"` around the `<?php` `?>` tags should be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select id="address_privacy" name="address_privacy" tabindex="auto">
    <option <?php  echo  $result['address_privacy'] == 'SHOW' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?> 
        value="SHOW">Show Physical Location
    </option>
    <option <?php echo  $result['address_privacy'] == 'HIDE' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
        value="HIDE">Hide Physical Location
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
<select id="address_privacy" name="address_privacy" tabindex="auto">
<?php if($result['address_privacy'] == 'SHOW'):?>
<option  <?php { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="SHOW">Show Physical Location</option>
<?php else : ?>
<option  { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="HIDE">Hide Physical Location</option>
<?php endif;?>

</select>
```

Regardless of HOW you accomplish this, you need to use `==` for the comparison, not `=`. And make sure you remove the `"` around the `<?php ?>` sections of your code.